# How to iterate an object of objects and print key and again iterate the value which is an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I have an object which I need to iterate and print the keys and again iterate the values which is an array. Below is the sample object.

```
{
"Product Details": [
    {
        "attribute_code": "type2",
        "label": "Variant / Model",
        "value": "100 4jet Vario"
    }
],
"_General": [
    {
        "attribute_code": "designer",
        "label": "Design by",
        "value": "Hansgrohe"
    },
    {
        "attribute_code": "delivery_time",
        "label": "Delivery Time",
        "value": "on stock"
    }
],
"_Characteristics": [
    {
        "attribute_code": "shape_outside",
        "label": "Shape",
        "value": "round"
    },
    {
        "attribute_code": "water_heater",
        "label": "Water heater",
        "value": "suitable for instantaneous water heaters"
    }
],
"_Color-Material-Surface": [
    {
        "attribute_code": "material",
        "label": "Material",
        "value": "metal / plastic"
    }
]
```

}

I am displaying the values in an accordion where the object key eg. "Product details" is accordion heading and inside the accordion the content is the value of the array which I need to map and display. Also these keys "Product details", "_General" are dynamic and will not be the same. Below is a screenshot how I want it to be displayed.
[image]

Comment: You should take a look at [`Object.entries(..)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

Answer (score 2):

You can use **Object.entries()** to iterate the object, it returns array of **key-value** pairs. As per your json data you can create component like this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Accordion = ({ title, data }) => {
  const [isExpanded, setExpanded] = useState(false);

  const onClickHeading = () => setExpanded(!isExpanded);

  return (
    <div>
      <h6 onClick={onClickHeading}>{title}</h6>
      {isExpanded && (
        <div>
          <ul>
            {data.map((item, index) => (
              <li key={'accordion-body-' + index}>
                {item.attribute_code} - {item.label} - {item.value}
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const accordionData = {
    'Product Details': [
      { attribute_code: 'type2', label: 'Variant / Model', value: '100 4jet Vario' },
    ],
    '_General': [
      { attribute_code: 'designer', label: 'Design by', value: 'Hansgrohe' },
      { attribute_code: 'delivery_time', label: 'Delivery Time', value: 'on stock' },
    ],
    '_Characteristics': [
      { attribute_code: 'shape_outside', label: 'Shape', value: 'round' },
      {
        attribute_code: 'water_heater',
        label: 'Water heater',
        value: 'suitable for instantaneous water heaters',
      },
    ],
    '_Color-Material-Surface': [
      { attribute_code: 'material', label: 'Material', value: 'metal / plastic' },
    ],
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {Object.entries(accordionData).map(([title, data], index) => (
        <Accordion key={'accordion-' + index} title={title} data={data} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Useful in my case.